# Changing CSS class with JavaScript has no effect

Tags: html, css, setattribute

I want my nav bar (that is in the form of a list) to stay invisible (display: none;) on page load, and to appear when something is clicked (currently using a button)

here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type=text/javascript>
function changeClass(){
document.getElementById("mainnav").setAttribute("class", "show");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<input  type="button" value="click" onClick="changeClass()">

<div id="mainnav">

 <ul >
<li>Home</li>
<li>Emergency Repair Service</li>
<li>Heating</li>
<li>Air Conditioning</li>
<li>Products</li>
<li>Specials</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>

</div><!--mainnav-->
```

Here is my CSS

```
#mainnav {
display:none;
}

ul li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}

.show {
display: block;
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Here is my javascript

```
function changeClass(){
document.getElementById("mainnav").setAttribute("class", "show");
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think js is good but problem is in css, try change it like below.

```
.show {
display: block !important;
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works. See my example here: http://jsbin.com/uyonuc

Are you sure you're setting it to be hidden from the CSS initially?

Also try adding a `!important` to `display:block` to make sure it overrides any other property.

Answer (score 1):

ID selector (`#mainnav`) rules have a higher precedence than class selector (`.show`) rules. Therefore, `display:none` will persist even after you assign your div the class `.show`.

You could initially use a `.hide` class and replace it with a `.show` or use an `!important` rule in your CSS.

An article on CSS specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.show {
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

to this:

```
#mainnav.show {
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

`display:block` in the `.show` class will then override `display:none` in the `#mainnav` selector, because the new rule is more specific.